# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am not a DB person, I am trying to run a SQL script provided to me, which throws the below error. Can someone please let me know how to fix it. Thanks in advance

```
[6550] ORA-06550: line 27, column 10:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the 
following:

   begin function pragma procedure
```

I am running this on Oracle v12.1, let me know if you need any other information.

Also, I tried executing the same on v12.2 intance, but still get the same error.

Here is the SQL that I am executing

```
DECLARE 
   type ah_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
   ah_cur ah_cursor;
   ah_unmatched_cur ah_cursor;
   PROCEDURE insertAHFromCursor(cur IN ah_cursor) 
        IS 
        type ah_row is record("ISSUE_ID" NUMBER(38,0),
        "SEQNUMBER" NUMBER(38,0),
        "ATTRGUID" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
        "AUDITTIME" NUMBER(19,0),
        "PROJECTVERSION_ID" NUMBER(38,0),
        "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
        "CONFLICT" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N',
        "OLDVALUE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
        "NEWVALUE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE));
        type TObjectTable is table of ah_row;
        ObjectTable$ TObjectTable;
      BEGIN
        LOOP
        fetch cur BULK COLLECT INTO ObjectTable$ LIMIT 1000;
        EXIT WHEN ObjectTable$.COUNT < 1;
        forall x in ObjectTable$.First..ObjectTable$.Last
        insert into audithistory(issue_id, seqNumber, attrGuid, auditTime, projectVersion_id, userName, conflict, oldValue, newValue)
        values (ObjectTable$(x).issue_id, ObjectTable$(x).seqNumber, ObjectTable$(x).attrGuid, ObjectTable$(x).auditTime, ObjectTable$(x).projectVersion_id, ObjectTable$(x).userName,  ObjectTable$(x).conflict, ObjectTable$(x).oldValue, ObjectTable$(x).newValue);
        commit;
        END LOOP;
      END;

      BEGIN
        OPEN ah_cur FOR
          SELECT aho.issue_id issue_id, aho.seqNumber seqNumber, aho.attrGuid attrGuid, aho.auditTime auditTime, 
            aho.projectVersion_id projectVersion_id, aho.userName userName, aho.conflict conflict,
            (CASE WHEN aho.oldValue IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
                WHEN alOld.lookupValue IS NULL THEN CAST(aho.oldValue as varchar2(500))
                ELSE CAST(alOld.lookupValue as varchar2(500)) END) oldValue,
            (CASE WHEN aho.newValue IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
                WHEN alNew.lookupValue IS NULL THEN CAST(aho.newValue as varchar2(500))
                ELSE CAST(alNew.lookupValue as varchar2(500)) END) newValue
        FROM audithistory_old aho
            INNER JOIN attr a ON aho.attrGuid = a.guid
            LEFT JOIN attrlookup alNew ON alNew.attrGuid = aho.attrGuid AND aho.newValue = alNew.lookupIndex
            LEFT JOIN attrlookup alOld ON alOld.attrGuid = aho.attrGuid AND aho.oldValue = alOld.lookupIndex
        WHERE a.attrType = 'CUSTOM'   
    insertAHFromCursor(ah_cur);
    close ah_cur;
    open ah_unmatched_cur for
        SELECT aho.issue_id issue_id, aho.seqNumber seqNumber, aho.attrGuid attrGuid, aho.auditTime auditTime, 
            aho.projectVersion_id projectVersion_id, aho.userName userName, aho.conflict conflict,
            (CASE WHEN aho.oldValue IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(aho.oldValue AS varchar2(500)) END) oldValue,
            (CASE WHEN aho.newValue IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(aho.newValue AS varchar2(500)) END) newValue
        FROM audithistory_old aho 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM audithistory ah 
            WHERE aho.issue_id = ah.issue_id AND aho.seqNumber = ah.seqNumber);
     insertAHFromCursor(ah_unmatched_cur);
    close ah_unmatched_cur;
END;
/
```

Comment: You seem to be making this much more complicated than it needs to be... why aren't you just doing simple `insert ... select` statements, instead of using cursors and collections? Anyway, at the moment you're missing a semicolon at the end of line 43, but that throws ORA-00933. Apart from that, it seems valid.

Comment: GIven the line number and position being reported, I'd guess this is actually a client issue, and whichever client you're running this through is confused by the blank line 28. Try to run it through SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope there you have procedure insertAHFromCursor it should be compiled first in database and then use that procedure inside the block

Step : 1

```
 PROCEDURE insertAHFromCursor(cur IN ah_cursor) 
        IS 
        type ah_row is record("ISSUE_ID" NUMBER(38,0),
        "SEQNUMBER" NUMBER(38,0),
        "ATTRGUID" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
        "AUDITTIME" NUMBER(19,0),
        "PROJECTVERSION_ID" NUMBER(38,0),
        "USERNAME" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
        "CONFLICT" CHAR(1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'N',
        "OLDVALUE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE),
        "NEWVALUE" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE));
        type TObjectTable is table of ah_row;
        ObjectTable$ TObjectTable;
      BEGIN
        LOOP
        fetch cur BULK COLLECT INTO ObjectTable$ LIMIT 1000;
        EXIT WHEN ObjectTable$.COUNT < 1;
        forall x in ObjectTable$.First..ObjectTable$.Last
        insert into audithistory(issue_id, seqNumber, attrGuid, auditTime, projectVersion_id, userName, conflict, oldValue, newValue)
        values (ObjectTable$(x).issue_id, ObjectTable$(x).seqNumber, ObjectTable$(x).attrGuid, ObjectTable$(x).auditTime, ObjectTable$(x).projectVersion_id, ObjectTable$(x).userName,  ObjectTable$(x).conflict, ObjectTable$(x).oldValue, ObjectTable$(x).newValue);
        commit;
        END LOOP;
      END;
```

Step 2:

```
DECLARE 
   type ah_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
   ah_cur ah_cursor;
   ah_unmatched_cur ah_cursor;

      BEGIN
        OPEN ah_cur FOR
          SELECT aho.issue_id issue_id, aho.seqNumber seqNumber, aho.attrGuid attrGuid, aho.auditTime auditTime, 
            aho.projectVersion_id projectVersion_id, aho.userName userName, aho.conflict conflict,
            (CASE WHEN aho.oldValue IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
                WHEN alOld.lookupValue IS NULL THEN CAST(aho.oldValue as varchar2(500))
                ELSE CAST(alOld.lookupValue as varchar2(500)) END) oldValue,
            (CASE WHEN aho.newValue IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
                WHEN alNew.lookupValue IS NULL THEN CAST(aho.newValue as varchar2(500))
                ELSE CAST(alNew.lookupValue as varchar2(500)) END) newValue
        FROM audithistory_old aho
            INNER JOIN attr a ON aho.attrGuid = a.guid
            LEFT JOIN attrlookup alNew ON alNew.attrGuid = aho.attrGuid AND aho.newValue = alNew.lookupIndex
            LEFT JOIN attrlookup alOld ON alOld.attrGuid = aho.attrGuid AND aho.oldValue = alOld.lookupIndex
        WHERE a.attrType = 'CUSTOM'   
    insertAHFromCursor(ah_cur);
    close ah_cur;
    open ah_unmatched_cur for
        SELECT aho.issue_id issue_id, aho.seqNumber seqNumber, aho.attrGuid attrGuid, aho.auditTime auditTime, 
            aho.projectVersion_id projectVersion_id, aho.userName userName, aho.conflict conflict,
            (CASE WHEN aho.oldValue IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(aho.oldValue AS varchar2(500)) END) oldValue,
            (CASE WHEN aho.newValue IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CAST(aho.newValue AS varchar2(500)) END) newValue
        FROM audithistory_old aho 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM audithistory ah 
            WHERE aho.issue_id = ah.issue_id AND aho.seqNumber = ah.seqNumber);
     insertAHFromCursor(ah_unmatched_cur);
    close ah_unmatched_cur;
END;
```

Comment: It's fine to declare a procedure (or function) within an anonymous block as the OP is doing.

Comment: Original Poster, i.e. the person who asked the question *8-)  Or sometimes Original Post, referring to the question itself.